# PowerShell -gt comparison operator not working

Tags: powershell

I am currently using a PowerShell script to read the output of a file and then if the number is higher than I want, it sends an email. Script is below -

```
$Output = 'D:\alec.data\QueuedJobss.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

if ($Queued -gt 1)
```

It is creating the file, but it's not sending it to me. I know my email scripts are working because they're the same ones I always use. It seems it's having a hard time interpreting the string. I do not receive any errors on the code.   The output it's reading from looks like this -

```
Summary of jobs on usctest01
Queued:                                6
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                           0
Successful:                   25863
Partially Successful:           113
Failed:                         184
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        26160
```

Answer (score 3):

if you check out `get-member` on `$Queued` by running `$Queued | gm` you will see this: `TypeName: System.String`

so `$Queued` is a string and thus `-gt` does not work. however if you cast the the variable as integer as follows (the `[int]` tells the variable to be an integer) you can use `-gt` as shown in your example:

```
[int]$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value
```

running `$Queued | gm` now will show you this: `TypeName: System.Int32`

Comment: Wow I think that worked! It's at least sending an email now...all I did was att [int] in front of $Queued like you said. That's all you need right?

Comment: Check out what .Matches.Value delivers.   I guess that it is delivering the value 1, meaning that one match was found.  I think you are trying to obtain the number that follows Queue.

Comment: Correct, is matches.value not what I want?

Comment: @WalterMitty when i run it it returns `6` .. so @AB2112 `matches.value` is exactly what you want.