# Greater than Powershell Script

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a script that's running a command, producing output, analyzing that output and if it finds the word Queued followed by a number greater than 100 it sends me an email. There are a lot of spaces after queued but I believe my code is correct to accommodate for those. Currently I am only receiving an email when the number is set to 0. Any other number set by -gt or -ge is not notifying me when it should.

Script -

```
$Output = 'D:\alec.data\QueuedJobs.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

[int]$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

if ($Queued -ge 100)
```

This is the output it's analyzing - 
Summary of jobs on usclwnbma01

```
Queued:                                130
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                         124
Successful:                   26913
Partially Successful:           114
Failed:                         186
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        27337
```

Comment: What happened since [6 hours ago when it was working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50418112/478656) ?

Comment: Evidently false alarm...the script was no longer giving errors but it can't seem to get past 0. I think it's having a problem translating the number or something

Answer (score 0):

$Queued returns a collection in my tests. So this should the right approach:

```
 $Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

foreach( $entry in $Queued) {
  if( [int]$entry -ge 100 ) {
    # do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Still only getting an email on 0.

Comment: Could you provide you input file for download?

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707193/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-powershell#answer-33707377)

first you need to assign the casted value to a variable before using it in the if condition.

```
$strQueued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

$Queued = [int]$strQueued

if ($Queued -ge 100)
```

Comment: Still only works with 0, any other number doesn't send an email

Comment: @AB2112, could you confirm that your regex is working correctly and returning expected output? I'm not sure if powershell supports non fixed width look behind. See details [here](https://regex101.com/r/K7odbX/1)

Comment: It's producing the file if that's what you're asking? If it doesn't support it what other options do I have?

Comment: @AB2112, see if you could `echo` (or its powershell equivalent) the value of `$strQueued` and confirm that its value is indeed 130 for the output given above

Comment: @AB2112 Try changing the regex to `Queued:\s+(\d+)` and change the first line to `$strQueued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern 'Queued:\s+(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1]`